# A mechanism in .NET to store large-sized response data for temporary use

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Currently, we are working with large-sized response data for search, pagination, and displaying details. Our approach involves storing the data in a physical file and subsequently reading it for pagination and presenting individual entry details. However, the response size is very huge, leading to performance issues during the file reading process, resulting in a slow-running application.

We are using .Net 6

Thanks in advance.

We are looking for alternative options to optimize performance.

Comment: _Currently, we are working with large-sized response data for search, pagination, and displaying details._ You tagged sql and Mongodb, where is this response data fetched from?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: We are working on hotel search module. We are getting hotel response from client api. We are storing it in temporary file. Same response is used for pagination and to display hotel information. But for city search data is very huge hence reading data, pagination, show hotel details taking some time. Hence looking for alternate solution

Comment: @DenisMicheal response data is fetched from external client api which is very huge. Can we use mongo db to store these temp data and then read it again to show hotel information. Will that help in performance?

Comment: On a search page we are showing hotels in the pagination format and to display hotel and rooming information we are reading response which is stored in the physical file

Comment: large-size can mean a lot of things, you should be more explicit. Take into account that regular mongo driver can work with documents not bigger than 16MB